# Где ошибка в коде PHP? фраймворк codeignither

Tags: php, codeigniter

Есть такой код, я хочу получить все записи по данному запросу.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d.%m.%Y')  as date_reg from history_sale hs WHERE hs.partner_id = '$partner_id';");
        $r = mysql_query($query);   
        $res_array= array();
        $count=0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
            $res_array[$count]=$row;
            $count++;
        }
        return $res_array;
```

Выдает ошибку

**Message: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource**

Comment: 100% SQL Injection. И mysql*** ?? Это реально codeignater? Посмотрите примеры по работе с базой данных в этом фреймворке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кроме текста сообщения об ошибке нужен ещё номер строки. Моё *предположение*: в SQL запросе ошибка, поэтому mysql_query("SELECT ...") вернул false, а не ресурс.

Либо ... лишний второй mysql_query($query);

Comment: Спасибо помогли, дело оказалось во втором mysql_query

Comment: И всё же я уверен, что в codeignater есть иной способ обращения к базе данных. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d.%m.%Y')  as date_reg from history_sale hs WHERE hs.partner_id = '$partner_id'";
```

Вот так будет работать. В твоем варианте $query не будет строкой, как это ожидает на входе следующая строка `$r = mysql_query($query);`

Comment: Точно, $query должен быть просто строкой, $r - результатом его исполнения